# "Cannot find symbol" al llamar a una clase desde un fichero JSP

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee

Hago esta llamada a la clase "CookieHandler" desde el inicio del JSP:

```
<% 
    CookieHandler handler = new CookieHandler();
    if(handler.checkLogged(request, response)){
%>
```

Sucede que no paro de tener este error, no sé por qué:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: source value 1.5 is obsolete and
>   will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: target value 1.5 is obsolete and
>   will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: To suppress warnings about obsolete
>   options, use -Xlint:-options.
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file:
>   /SeccionUsuarios.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find
>   symbol   symbol:   class CookieHandler   location: class
>   org.apache.jsp.SeccionUsuarios_jsp
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file:
>   /SeccionUsuarios.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: cannot find
>   symbol   symbol:   class CookieHandler   location: class
>   org.apache.jsp.SeccionUsuarios_jsp

La clase "CookieHandler" está en el paquete por defecto del proyecto, pues este proyecto sólo es para enseñar algunas cosas de Java EE (es decir, nada serio), pero sigue extrañándome por qué tengo este error. ¿Alguien sabe qué sucede?

Comment: Ya he retirado el voto de cierre :) Sobre tu problema: Prueba de hacer un Clean & Rebuild.

Comment: @MiquelColl Sigue fallando :(

Comment: Quizá [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25706217/1468942) te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la descripción de tu situación:

> La clase "CookieHandler" está en el paquete por defecto del proyecto.

Los JSPs no pueden acceder a las clases que se encuentren en el paquete por defecto del proyecto (servlets incluidos). Coloca la clase dentro de un paquete y luego, en tu JSP, importa la clase:

```
<%@ page import="paquete.para.CookieHandler" %>
```

---

Recomiendo que evites mostrar scriptlets a gente que está aprendiendo Java EE. No se consideran buena práctica para aplicaciones reales.